# How to make phone number suggestion show up on keyboard of type PhonePad?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, swift4

I am trying to get the suggestion of the phone number to show up above the keyboard in the gray rectangle (like it does or email by default), but I am unable to get it to show up. Instead sometimes the email suggestions from the email text field shows up...

How do I do this?

I've tried this:

```
        email_phoneInputField.keyboardType = .phonePad
//        email_phoneInputField.returnKeyType = .default
        email_phoneInputField.autocapitalizationType = .none
        email_phoneInputField.autocorrectionType = .no
        email_phoneInputField.textContentType = .telephoneNumber
        email_phoneInputField.reloadInputViews()
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, I used this code:

```
email_phoneInputField.keyboardType = .phonePad
email_phoneInputField.returnKeyType = .default
email_phoneInputField.autocapitalizationType = .none
email_phoneInputField.autocorrectionType = .no
email_phoneInputField.textContentType = .telephoneNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you cannot get the suggestion of phone number by system keyboard.If you really want the suggestion from keyboard, try the third-party keyboard.

————————————————————————————————————————————

I tried what you said and it didn't work for me as like before.I cannot see the gray rectangle in the mode of system keyboard.

There must be something wrong.Could you post a screenshot about the suggestion?

Comment: so I think this is actually not true